# How to send & receive data using NSNotificationCenter in iOS (XCode6.4)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing an issue with NSNotificationCenter.

I am not able to send message and receive message using NSNotificationCenter in latest ios 8.4 (XCode 6.4)

Please check the following code:

1) I want to send data using first view controller to another view.
so i have written the following code in first viewcontroller:

When user btn clicked method as following :

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender 
{ 
  [self postNotification];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"asGo" sender:self]; 
} 

-(void)postNotification{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
}
```

2) In Second view controller i have added observer in ViewWillApper  as following :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(eventListenerDidReceiveNotification:)
                                                         name:@"MyNotification"
                                                       object:nil];
}


-(void)eventListenerDidReceiveNotification:(NSNotification*)txt
{
 NSLog(@"i got notfication:");
}
```

so eventListenerDidReceiveNotification is not called while come on view.
But i am not getting above log while i come on second vc with navigation

Comment: Does your second view controller is on memory ? or have you ever open second vc

Comment: I need on while navigation on second vc that time selector method is not called .

Comment: Once check method where you are adding the observer

Comment: can you provide more code along with navigation flow?

Comment: FirstViewContrller : When user btn clicked method as following :- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
    
    [self postNotification];
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"asGo" sender:self];
}
-(void)postNotification{
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
}

Comment: In SecondViewController i am calling this method on ViewWillApper as following :-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                             selector:@selector(eventListenerDidReceiveNotification: name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
}
- (void)eventListenerDidReceiveNotification:(NSNotification*)txt{
    NSLog(@"i got notfication:");
}
but i am not getting above log while i come on second vc with navigation

Comment: Once add your observer in this method and check  :  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

Comment: i have checked using this method but never method called. plz kinldy help me.

Comment: This problem seems a good example to be resolved with delegates. NSNotification is not the right solution to send messages between controllers when you click a button. Use delegates

Comment: @SonGoku68, there is no need for a delegate here either. He just needs to pass data from the first VC to the second. It can be done in the `prepareForSegue` method without any unnecessary complications. @MukundRaj, `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't work the way you want it to work.

Comment: @FreeNickname I don't think it's that the case he is talking about. As I understand he has already two controllers loaded and he want to pass information when click a button. Make sense with his implementation with notifications otherwise it's not possible to listen a notification when it's sent before you create the second view controller. It's for this reason because I supposed he has both controllers already loaded and the reason because delegates it's the best solution.

Comment: @SonGoku68, It is correct, that you have to have two VCs already present in order to pass information between them via `NSNotificationCenter`. But I saw `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the question and assumed that segues is what he uses, so the only way to get the second VC is in the `prepareForSegue` method. But if he is going to do it in the `prepareForSegue` method, he can as well do it without the `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: @SonGoku68 I think, I'll give it a shot in a moment. It is completely useless, but I've got nothing to do, and I've been drinking all night long, so I'm just in the right condition to pass data between two consequent VCs via the `NSNotificationCenter` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't work like a post office. It only delivers notifications if someone actually listens to them at the moment they arrived. This is the reason your `eventListenerDidReceiveNotification` method is not being called: you add an observer in `viewWillAppear`, which is called after the segue (I assume that you're using segues because of the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method in your code) is finished, so it's definitely called after `postNotification` has been called.

So, in order to pass data via NSNotificationCenter you have to add an observer **before** you post a notification.
The following code is completely useless and unnecessarily overcomplicated, you shouldn't do anything like that, but since you keep insisting on using a scheme like this, here you go:

```
//Didn't test this code. Didn't even compile it, to be honest, but it should be enough to get the idea.

NSString * const SOUselessNotificationName = @"MyUselessNotification";

#pragma mark - FIRST VC

@interface SOFirstVC : UIViewController
@end

@implementation SOFirstVC

NSString * const SOasGoSegueIdentifer = @"asGo";

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender { 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SOasGoSegueIdentifer sender:self]; 
}

-(void)postNotification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SOUselessNotificationName object:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifer isEqualToString:SOasGoSegueIdentifer]) {
        SOSecondVC *destinationVC = (SOSecondVC *)segue.destinationViewController;

        [destinationVC registerToReceiveNotificationsFromObject:self];
        [self postNotification];
    }
}

@end

#pragma mark - SECOND VC

@interface SOSecondVC : UIViewController

-(void)registerToReceiveNotificationsFromObject:(id)object;

@end

@implementation SOSecondVC

-(void)registerToReceiveNotificationsFromObject:(id)object {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:(eventListenerDidReceiveUselessNotification:) name:SOUselessNotificationName object:object];
}

-(void)eventListenerDidReceiveUselessNotification:(NSNotification*)uselessNotification {
 NSLog(@"I got a useless notfication! Yay!");
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter basically has 3 steps

- Adding Observer like `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(open:) name:@"OpenDetail" object:nil];`
- Posting Notification `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"OpenDetail" object:self];`
- Removing Observer  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"OpenDetail" object:nil];`

I think you are posting your notification and then later adding observer while it's vie versa. You have to add observer first then post notification. 
HTH

Comment: I want to get data after post notification on second vc.

Comment: not being captain obvious but why don't you pass data using segue. Notification doesn't work that way

Comment: plz let me know , how can i send data using nsnotificationCenter

Comment: @MukundRaj NsNotification will not work as you are posting a notification when there's no observer to listen to it. You can use delegates or either use segues to pass data

Comment: @Misha Yes, we can pass data as following four ways like : @1) Using Delgates and Protocols @2) using segues reference @3)Using KVO @4) Using NsnotificationCenter. but i am not able to pass data using NSNotificationCenter.  i have done three ways but i need fourth one , so i m facing thiese issue so give me solution using NSNotiification?

Comment: @MukundRaj If you want to do this using NSNotificationCenter you'll have to add observer in fisrtView Controler  and post notification from sceondVC

Answer (score 0):

First you have to setup the data you want to send

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myObject forKey:@"aKey"];
```

Then you post it with the data like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"MyNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

And finally you read the data off the notification:

```
-(void)eventListenerDidReceiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
 NSLog(@"i got notification:");
 NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
 NSString *myObject = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aKey"];
}
```